# how to insert multiple List<string> to a datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

How can i create datagridview using 4 different List.

```
List<string> experience = new List<string>();
    List<string> Cname = new List<string>();
    List<string> Clink = new List<string>();
    List<string> Ccomp = new List<string>();
```

I have to create four columns in datagridview based on above 4 list. How can i do that. Every `List<string>` content will be added to datagridview column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not bind with multiple, for this you should create a collection which can store these data in a single.

you can use DataTable or can create a class with four properties, and then make a List of that class, or you can use Tuple class if want to use predefined .net class.

you can try this if using Tuple class, but all list must have same count.

```
    var list = new List<Tuple<string,string,string,string>>();

    for(int i=0; i<experience.Count; i++)
       list.Add(new Tuple<string,string,string,string>(experience[i],Cname[i],Clink[i],Ccomp[i]));

    dataGridView.DataSource = list;
```

or for datatable you can try

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table");
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{ 
    new DataColumn("experience", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Cname", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Clink", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Ccomp", typeof(string))
 });

for(int i=0; i<experience.Count; i++){
   var newRow = dt.NewRow();
    newRow["experience"] = experience[i];
    newRow["Cname"] = Cname[i];
    newRow["Clink"] = Clink[i];
    newRow["Ccomp"] = Ccomp[i];
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
 }

dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create DataTable with your four lists and bind your datagridview  with this DataTable.

Comment: `DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(experience);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;`. I tried this , but its giving invalid arguments. Can you give me an example how to create datatable with above four list. [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable). From here i got the code to try.